# WildFly 27.0.1 stops with NotYetReadyException when using hibernate custom types

Tags: hibernate, wildfly

We've just migrated our application from Java EE 8 on WildFly 20 to Jakarta EE 10 on WildFly 27. So far, everything worked fine, just one problem is left.
When using hibernate-types for JSON mapping, the server is not starting and closes with the following exception, that the BeanManager ist not ready:

```
10:24:02,067 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Test-WebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#xxx.PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Test-WebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#xxx.PU": org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.NotYetReadyException: CDI BeanManager not (yet) ready to use
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:214)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.NotYetReadyException: CDI BeanManager not (yet) ready to use
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.JpaCompliantLifecycleStrategy$NamedBeanImpl.initialize(JpaCompliantLifecycleStrategy.java:231)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl$NamedBeanImpl.initialize(CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl$NamedBeanImpl.getBeanInstance(CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.internal.ManagedBeanRegistryImpl$ContainedBeanManagedBeanAdapter.getBeanInstance(ManagedBeanRegistryImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.setExplicitCustomType(BasicValue.java:828)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(BasicValueBinder.java:1238)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.cfg.SetBasicValueTypeSecondPass.doSecondPass(SetBasicValueTypeSecondPass.java:26)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1782)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421)
    at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate6@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:45)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:171)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager.createCreationalContext(jakarta.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual)" because "this.beanManager" is null
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.JpaCompliantLifecycleStrategy$NamedBeanImpl.initialize(JpaCompliantLifecycleStrategy.java:228)
    ... 23 more
```

I've reduced the code to a minimal example with a single entity left. The Problem is just the `@Type(JsonType.class)` line. If removed, server starts fine.

```
@Type(JsonType.class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
private List<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
```

Does anyone has some hints for me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: tracked in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16069

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Did you get around it in any way?

Comment: issue was fixed in later versions of hibernate, which are included in latest WildFly. We are on WF29 currently, which works fine (migration to WF30 currently in testing)